# jest can't transpile static state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

Below code failed with jest, I got `unexpected token error`

```
export default class Search extends Component {
  state = { // problem is here
    q: ''
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      q: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="search" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm using babel-7, any plugin I need to pull in for jest?

I'm using jest version ^23.6.0

Comment: What is not working in jest? can you show relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties) if you want to use class properties. So install it then make sure you add it as a plugin in your .babelrc file like this:

```
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use a constructor and define your state with `this.state`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
        q: ''
    }
}
```

or use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties.

Class fields are still a stage 3 proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields